# Why I can't import UIKit in .swift file in sources folder at swift playgrounds?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, swift-playground

So I want to make a swift file in the sources folder that imports UIKit, but it says that no such module 'UIKit', why is it like that?

[image: Here's the picture]

Can someone help?

Comment: Is it iOS or macOS in the settings?

Comment: It is iOS. I have search all the solutions but still none of them works

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: Any solution for it?